# Google Maps API - Place Image outside a InfoWindow

Tags: css, image, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I need to customize a Google Maps **InfoWindow**.

In particular I want an image to "hang over the edge" of the InfoWindow. But when I place the image `absolute` within the `InfoWindow-DIV` it disappears behind the `border` of my InfoWindow.

Adding a `z-index` changes nothing.

Hope I made my point clear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many custom window solution , see this one for example:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

If you want something outside of the infoMarker border, you'd better use a custom solution.
The built in one is good for the simple stuff.

Comment: i'll have a look. too bad though... i like the basic one :)

Comment: InfoBubbles are great. They lack some features of the InfoWindow but still a good solution! Thanks!